# where can I download MongoDb Java Driver 4.0.1 with MongoDB Reactive Streams Driver feature and set Spring Data to use it

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, maven, reactive-programming, spring-data-mongodb

Maybe a very naive question but I really can't find it. Honestly I would expect to find it in maven repository but I didn't. At the moment of this question the most recent available version is

[maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.12.2)

I looked also at:

[github team](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver)

and

[github documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/)

You may wonder why I am interested on version 4 since mongo-java-driver-3.12.2.jar is garanted as compatible with MongoDb 4 ([compatibility table](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.0/upgrading/)). Basically, I am designed a significant Reactive Arquitecture and I am trying my best with Reactive, Non-blocking, Back Pressure control stuck and MongoDb is the main candidate for our private cloud. So I really want to start taking advantage any improvement found in new version.

So my main question is: where is MongoDb Java Driver 4 available. A surrounding question is: is Spring-Data ready to use it? Should I change either something in maven or add manually to my classpath?

The bellow POM brings me both mongo-driver-core and mongo-driver-async version 3.11.2

Pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.reactive</groupId>
    <artifactId>fluxdemo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>fluxdemo</name>
    <description>Projeto parte da arquitetura de referência</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Sorry, I am wondering why my question was downvoted (I am not complaining, I just want to understand the reason). Is there some logic behind to find such MongoDb Java Library which isn't in maven neither on github. If so, my bad, I don't know. If not, why downvote it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MongoDB reactive streams driver can be obtained via [org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-reactivestreams](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.mongodb/mongodb-driver-reactivestreams).

Spring Data MongoDB 3.0 (to be picked up by Spring Boot 2.3) will add support for the 4.x MongoDB Drivers.
Please mind the [Upgrading from 2.x](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/3.0.0.RC1/reference/html/#upgrading.2-3) section in the reference documentation.

Comment: @Cristoph thanks, you certainly answered my question. If you had the chance to add how you reach Sonatype page I will learn a bit more. I mean, if you search in https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver you can find only 3.X.X version even updated this month. I couldn't find while googling before. Is there some logic or reason for I not finding in mvnrepository?